# Postgresql: Split column by 2 different delimiters

Tags: postgresql

I have a string like:

```
gg__1234_1232
```

I would like to split the string after `__` into a separate column.  I have tried using `SPLIT_PART(string,'__',2)`, however this returns the entire string after `__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting by two underscores: `__`, split it by just a single underscore `_` and grab the next element:

```
SELECT split_part('gg__1234_1232', '_', 3);
```

Of course this won't work if it's an arbitrary number of underscores. IF that's the case, then you can hit the string with `regexp_replace` first to squish your multiple underscores into a single underscore, then hit it with `split_part`:

```
SELECT split_part(REGEXP_REPLACE('gg_1234_1232','[_]+','_'), '_', 2);
```